# Need help increasing max tx size for removing lp pool transaction, can only remove negligible amounts from lp pool at a time

Tags: smartcontracts, pool, cryptocurrency

I can only remove negligible amounts of crypto from my lp pool (less than 0.000001) bnb at a time. When I go to write my contract it shows that gas is too high and there may be a contract error. What can I do to get my liquidity removed?

Can give reward to helper

Token Contract: 0x56E0B56f78F70AAeac9f855434fFC4089DD48B1B

LP pool: 0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c

tried writing the contract under contract creator account and that did not work. Says may be error in contract and gas too high to estimate